# How to unwrap NSMutableDictionary.allkeys in optional String Array

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, optional-variables

I am trying to get all the key values of NSMutableDictionary as String Array. I am using this `myNSMutableDictionary.allkeys` to get the values as an Array but I cannot find a way to unwrap the key values.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for (key, _) in NSMutableDictionary {
        println("THIS IS MY NEW KEY\(key)")
    }
```

And I tried this

```
var myArray:NSArray =  myNSMutableDictionary.allKeys
var string:NSString? = uniqueIDArray[0] as? NSString
println("This is unwraped value\(string!)")
```

And this

```
var myArray:Array =  myNSMutableDictionary.allKeys
println("This is unwraped value\(myArray[0])")
```

I keep getting the value as `Optional("kMSZgoTmiX")` instead of `kMSZgoTmiX` which is the key value I need

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: What's the problem with what you tried?

Comment: This is what I get THIS IS MY NEW KEYOptional("kMSZgoTmiX")     I am trying to get this  THIS IS MY NEW KEY kMSZgoTmiX

Comment: You know you don't need myArray:NSArray or string:NSString? the part after the colon is inferred from the type you're assigning to it, so it's redundant. You only need the : format on the left of the equals if the right side is unknown or type cannot be inferred from it.

Comment: Also if you're using Swift, why bother with NSArray and NSDictionary? I believe they're toll free bridged with Swift's types. And Swifts types are easier to use.  Unless you're interacting with something that hands back one from ObjC.

Comment: Also you need to be specific about the error as the first comment said to help people zone in on the problem without wasting more time reverse engineering and studying than necessary to help you.

Comment: @TalZion What did you get the second attempt?

Comment: var keys:[String] = myNSDictionary!.allKeys as [String]

Comment: @JavierFloresFont - Nice, but you can write it without :String after keys on the left side of the =, because the type is inferred from the right side of the = sign

Comment: var keys = myNSDictionary!.allKeys as [String]

Comment: @TalZion - The optionals add up. So if myNSDictionary is an optional, and allKeys is an optional (because it might not have anything to return), then you have nested optionals. I forget if you can dereference them with !! but there's usually a better way to do it, like Javier did, than that if it is allowed.

Comment: Thank you Javier, I tried what you suggested, I keep getting an error when I place !. I had to use NSMutableDictionary to set values but still get the values as optionals. What I am trying to do is for every UIImage I take, I want to give it a unique code and store the data where the unique code is the key for the UIImage. Can you please help with maybe a better solution? At the end, I will also need the key values as string

Answer (score 1):

So you've got a dictionary with values that are strings (and keys that are something, assume String):

```
var dictionaryOfStringValues : [String:String] = /* your dictionary */
```

And you want to iterate over the contents:

```
for (key, val) in dictionaryOfStringValues {
  // use key and val
}
```

If you just want the values in a way you can easily iterate over:

```
var theValues = dictionaryOfStringValues.values
```

If you insist that `theValues` be an `Array`:

```
   var theValuesAsAnArray = Array(dictionaryOfStringValues.values)
```

If you are starting with an NSMutableDictionary, then convert it at the point where it FIRST ENTERS your Swift code into a Swift Dictionary.  Use an `as` variant to do that.  After that, pure Swift.

Like this:

```
  7> for (key, value) in ["a":1, "b":2] { 
  8.     println (key) 
  9.     println (value) 
 10. }    
b
2
a
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let myNSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

myNSMutableDictionary["myKey1"] = 5
myNSMutableDictionary["myKey2"] = 10
myNSMutableDictionary["myKey3"] = 15

let myKeysArrayUnsorted =  myNSMutableDictionary.allKeys as [String]
let myValuesArrayUnsorted =  myNSMutableDictionary.allValues as [Int]

let keyString = myKeysArrayUnsorted[0]  // "myKey2"
let keyValue  = myNSMutableDictionary[keyString] as Int // 10

println("This is my first unsorted key \(keyString) = \(keyValue)")

let myKeysArraySorted =  (myNSMutableDictionary.allKeys as [String]).sorted(<)

for key in myKeysArraySorted {
    println(myNSMutableDictionary[key]!)  // 5 10 15
}
```